# Upload an image and store in database and retrieve using php code

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to view an image that I uploaded but I am getting this type of error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\imageupload\outputimage.php on line 12
```

my code for viewing image is given below:
rest of the code is working well .
I uploaded image successfully but problem is occurring on viewing image.

```
<?php

include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT images_path FROM  images_tbl ORDER by images_id DESC";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$select_query) or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){

?>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">

<tbody><tr>

<td>

<img src="<?php echo $row[" images_path"]; ="" ?="">" alt=" " />">


</td>

</tr>

</tbody></table>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with these extra '=' signs?? <img src="<?php echo $row[" images_path"]; ="" ?="">" alt=" " />">

Comment: Actually , I copied the code from other website and I removed all the errors but became confuse in this error.

Comment: ok then change the line as i mentioned below and see if it worked..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
<img src="<?php echo $row[" images_path"]; ?>" alt=" " />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting the line that prints the image with:

```html
<img src="<?php echo $row[" images_path"]; ?>" alt=" " />
```